# Makefile rule with no target

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I'm debugging a makefile, and in a macro expansion it creates a rule with no target (as so:)

```
: | directoryA
    @echo running $@
    ...
```

I've looked it up online, and the makefile documentation seems to hint (but not explicitly state) that there should be at least one target.

With my current version of make (gnu Make 4.2.1), it's not killing me, but I'm just wondering whether this is considered undefined behavior or whether this is supported, and if so, what it should do.

Comment: The GNU make source code says: _We accept and ignore rules without targets for compatibility with SunOS 4 make._

Comment: Thanks -- that's good to know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I've looked it up online, and the makefile documentation seems to hint (but not explicitly state) that there should be at least one target.

Different `make`s may behave differently.  They may even exhibit variant handling of specific makefile syntax matters depending on the content of the makefile -- for example, a makefile may be interpreted differently if it starts with a rule for the `.POSIX:` special target than an otherwise identical makefile without that rule is interpreted.

Overall, however, if you want some sort of general idea of what should be considered correct then [the POSIX standard's defintion of `make`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/make.html) is a reasonably good baseline.  It says:

> Target rules are formatted as follows:
>
> ```
> target [target...]: [prerequisite...][;command]
> [<tab>command<tab>command...]
>
> line that does not begin with <tab>
> ```
>
> **Target entries are specified by a <blank>-separated, *non-null* list of
> targets**, then a <colon>, [...]

(emphasis added).  It furthermore goes on to say that

> Applications shall select target names from the set of characters
> consisting solely of periods, underscores, digits, and alphabetics
> from the portable character set

, from which we can infer that the syntax description is talking about the rule text *after* macro expansion, since macro references can appear in the target lists of rules (or literally anywhere in a makefile, per the spec), but the characters `$`, `(`, `)`, `{`, and `}` appearing in macro references are not among those that can appear in targets.

*That* specification of makefiles' expected contents does explicitly state that target lists are non-empty, and it is reasonable to treat it as authoritative where your specific `make`'s documentation does not override it.

> I'm just wondering whether [an empty target list] is considered undefined behavior or
> whether this is supported

Your combination of makefile and runtime macro values does not conform to the requirements of POSIX `make`.  The spec does not define what should happen in this case, so in that sense the behavior is undefined, but "undefined behavior" isn't as strong a concept in this area as it is in, say, the C and C++ language specifications.

In view of that, I would account it a makefile flaw for any rule's target list to be empty (after macro expansion).  Although the `make` you are presently using may accept it without complaint, other `make`s, including future versions of your present `make`, may reject it or worse.

Answer (score 1):

Rule does expect one or more targets, there really are no two ways about it in the docs. For instance GNU make [docs](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Rule-Syntax.html#Rule-Syntax) notation:

```
targets : prerequisites
        recipe
```

Or [`1p`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/make.1p.html) section manpage:

```
target [target...]: [prerequisite...][;command]
```

Illumos:

```
target [:|::] [dependency] ... [; command] ...
               [command]
               ...
```

After all how would you refer to a target that had no name? I would assume no target rule should be an error...

However, I've tried different flavors of make (BSD, Illumos, GNU) and with varying degree of leniency (GNU make for instance seemed to also not care about syntax of prerequisites any more) or lack thereof they all seemed to have processed the line and possibly following tab indented block as a rule (with a recipe)... which then was ignored (also for the purpose of determining the default target).

I guess a rationale for this actually being consider valid `Makefile`... you could end up in this situation also with:

```
$(VAR):
        @echo foobar

other:
        @echo barbaz
```

In case `VAR` is undefined or empty, you'd end up with a such empty target as well.

Comment: This is almost exactly what's happening -- the parameter to the macro is being run through `$(filter ...)` and it ends up empty in some cases, and the macro wasn't smart enough to ifdef it out.   Notice that in the gnu make documentation, `prerequisites` can be empty, and it therefore stands that `targets` could also be empty, so I was a bit hesitant to declare it a bug.  -- the POSIX definition is much more clear, and thus I will go with that and raise an issue.